# Introduce Data manually (iOS DB)

Tags: ios, xcode

Im developing an iOS App and I need basically two things: 1) write Data manually into a Database. 2) Just read Data and display it. (an offline Database would be also cool).  What Database should I use? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean manually. Do you have data ready and you want it already in DB?

Comment: Yes I have the data ready. I want to introduce it "manually" in the DB so the App only reads it. I don't want to write something from the App in the DB, just read.

Comment: What does "data" mean exactly? 100 records? Thousands? A million? What about relationships, is everything one table? Everything from simple text files to a bundled SQLite database might be suitable.

Comment: Yes, about 1000 records. Everything one table (1:N relationship)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a plist, and add your data, & read it. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/how-do-i-get-a-plist-as-a-dictionary-in-swift)
2. Use Realm : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673370/best-way-to-build-a-pre-filled-realm-database)

Comment: Thanks! I will use Realm. I just found the way to add the data manually and not through the App.